# Why does `with` use `__enter__` of the class, not the object?

Tags: python, dynamic, with-statement

While experimenting with patching a context manager at runtime, I noticed that the following code does not behave as I expected:

```
class B:
    def __enter__(self):
        print('normal')
    def __exit__(self, *stuff):
        pass

    def modify(self, x):
        def other(self):
             print('not normal: ', x)
        self.__enter__ = other.__get__(self, type(self))

def main():
    b = B()
    b.__enter__()
    b.modify('hi')
    b.__enter__()
    with b:
        print('in with')
    b.__enter__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Executed, this prints:

```
normal
not normal:  hi
normal
in with
not normal:  hi
```

While the first part of `main`, with the explicit calls to `__enter__`, behaves as expected (the method *is* correctly modified), the `with`-statement seems to ignore this.

After some search, I found that the according [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) shows an example translation, which explains the behaviour; namely, the translation of the `with mgr: ...` internally uses something like

```
type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
```

instead of a direct method call, like I was doing above.

And I was wondering why that is done. Is it just to prevent people like me from messing around, or is there a deeper reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something called [special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) defined in the language description. Basically, this kind of lookup (using `type(obj).__method__(obj)`) happens for all "magic methods"; two reasons are given:

- Performance optimizations are possible
- There are cases with only work correctly with this variant, namely when special lookup defers to the type (like, `int.__hash__` being not the same thing as `type(int).__hash__`, which we usually really want)

Comment: I may not have fully understood the second argument. So improve it, if you want.